# Charging a battery from both solar panel and wind generator

Tags: current, motor, ac, dc

I am a complete newbie to electronics. I have taken up a project that basically aims to generate power using solar and wind energy due to personal interest and have done research but I seem to have hit a dead-end.

I have a 10 watt solar panel, 17.28 V (Vmp) <del>that gives me current in the "AC" form</del> DC.

I have used a stepper motor with the following features:

- 2 Phase
- Rated Voltage : 12V
- Rated Current : 0.33A
- Winding resistance: 32.6 Ω
- Winding inductance: 48 mH

UPDATE: I just went over the specifications again of the stepper motor, and it is a **DC motor.**  The DC motor is 12 volts output, The solar panel as mentioned before is also the about the same. I know how to produce electricity using the motor as well after a bit of research, i used a propeller that turns the motor to produce power now. The question now is, i have two DC sources and I want to charge one battery with it that will store the energy produced. How do I do it safely and connect both to one battery ? Thanks for putting up with me, although i sound very stupid i am still trying to learn. Thanks and merry xmas !!

Comment: Part numbers and links to data sheets, please. Solar panels are normally DC. Why do you think yours is AC? What do you want to do with the stepper motor? If you don't have a data sheet a photo may help. Please edit and add the information **to your question** and not here in the comments.

Comment: [After update] You distinguish by reading the data sheets. Post the links and photos. We can't guess what you've got.

Comment: That's a DC solar panel - not AC. It should be suitable for charging a 12 V lead-acid battery or similar. At 1000 W/m² from the Sun you will get about 1 A into the battery.

Comment: "Winding resistance : 32 ohms" ... if you can generate 12V in the stepper (unlikely) then at 0.1A you'll lose over 3V in the windings, and see only 9V at the terminals.

Comment: You *might* get better help if the question is clearer. I assume part of your question about how to use a stepper motor as a generator, and charge a battery using that. Then another part is how to use a solar cell to charge the same battery. Then finally how to combine the two to charge a shared battery. Is that correct? The solar cell is DC, so the title of the question "(2 AC sources)" seems misleading.

Comment: Well done for improving your question. One further point. The stepper motor is driven using switched DC, so it is called a DC motor. However, it will not produce DC. It will instead produce AC. To think about this, ignore one coil, connect the other to an oscilloscope (if you have access to one), or make an 'AC detector' (two LEDs connected in parallel but opposite polarities, and with a resistor). Turn the motor, and AC will be generated. This is fixable with a set of diodes connected as a "bridge rectifier" to produce varying-voltage DC. Merry Christmas, and best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK6CTV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You're going to end up doing something like this. The solar panel will generate a current and the charger circuit will regulate the current to the battery by regulating its output voltage. The wind generator will generate a voltage output and its charger will regulate current to the battery in the same way as the solar charger.

A pair of diodes could be used to prevent each side back-feeding into the other when it's not supplying. In practice the diodes may cause a little difficulty in sensing the true battery voltage - but you're a long way from this point.

My advice is to build each circuit separately and power a simple load such as a bulb or small DC motor. Progress then to charging a battery with each one separately. When you get each working you can then tackle the combination of the two.

Comment: Thank you !! I will definitely try it using a small load at first until i get more brave with circuits and concepts and then explore further.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad to permit a response here except to provide few general recommendations.

1. Learn all you can about your individual power production methods before considering how to combine their outputs.
2. You have good specifications for the solar panel. Learn how to interpret those specifications. Vmp and Imp are the voltage and current at the maximum power point. Vmp X Imp = Pmak, the maximum power that the panel will produce when pointed directly at the sun on the brightest day. Do research on maximum power point tracking.
3. A stepper motor is probably not the best choice for use as a generator. You should use a permanent-magnet DC motor (PMDC) with brushes and a commutator or a 3-phase, brushless DC motor (BLDC). PMDC motors are used in many battery operated toys, tools, appliances and vehicle accessories. BLDC motors are used in computer fans, printers, disc drives etc, but they often have electronic circuits built into them in a way that prevents them from being used as generators. If you can connect directly to the phase coils, BLDC motors work as AC generators.
4. A micro grid is a system of solar panels, generators, batteries, charge controllers etc. to supply a network of loads. Do more research on micro grids and their components. Some other possible components are buck converters, boost converters and inverters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the solar panel  produces DC and the stepper motor AC. You will need to convert AC to DC.  Also for solar-panel you need a controller that will step up the voltage of the solar panel to match that of the battery if needed a silicon cell has an open circuit voltage of about 0.7v, and make sure that the voltage produced by the turbine matches that of the solar panel. Then you can connect the two DC power sources in parallel. Also you will need some protection circuitry for your generators. For a beginner this is no easy task so I will say do your hw and take time to set it up safely.  Also make sure you read the specs of your type of battery chemistry and do some research on it that way you don't damage it.

Ps sorry I couldn't find how to comment here I am a beginner.